# Car Hire Ireland/Wales/England

Tags: automobiles, ireland, england

I'm flying into Ireland in Sept. 2017 and want to hire a car for ± 30 days - BUT I want to take it to Wales on the ferry then to London and Southern England and return it to Gatwick on Oct 10?  Can't seem to find a car hire company in Ireland that allows that?

Answer (score 7):

It does not surprise me that you cannot do an international car hire like that. I would recommend dropping the Irish car off near the ferry and hiring another on the other side.

If you are going through Wales only to reach southern England I would consider using the train to get to Southern England and rent a car once you get there.

Comment: I thought about changing car at the ferry but did not find a car hire place to leave with. I look again. I'm touring in Wales for a while so I need a car too. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Which ferry route are you planning to take from Ireland to Wales? [Dooley](https://www.dan-dooley.ie/car-rental-hire-dublin-port.htm) seem to have a meet and greet service at Dublin port and [Herz](https://www.hertz.co.uk/p/car-hire/uk/holyhead/holyhead-port-terminal-building) and [Europcar](https://www.europcar.ie/destinations/united-kingdom/holyhead/holyhead-port-meet-greet) seem to do something similar in Holyhead.